Can anyone help me show, using the integral definition of the Gamma function, that it can be expressed as a Gaussian integral?
$$
\Gamma(n) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^t t^{n - 1} dt
$$

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.
